# PHP nome de variável dinâmico, de acordo com valor de outra variável

Tags: php

Imaginem que eu tenha o código  abaixo:

```
<?php

$linha1 = 0;
$linha2 = 0;
$linha3 = 0;
$linha4 = 0;
$linha5 = 0;

// Array com 5 numeros
$cincoNumeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for($i=0;$i<50;$i++) {

    // Misturo aleatoriamente o array acima
    shuffle($cincoNumeros);
    // Seleciono um array unitário (um número) no array que foi misturado. 
    $umNumero = array_slice($cincoNumeros, 0, 1);
    // Pego o valor do index do array $umNumero
    $valor = $umNumero[0];

    // Agora, de acordo com esse número sorteado, incremendo a variavel correspondente:

    switch ($valor) {
        case 1:
        $linha1 += 1;
        break;
        case 2:
        $linha2 += 1;
        break;
        case 3:
        $linha3 += 1;
        break;
        case 4:
        $linha4 += 1;
        break;
        case 5:
        $linha5 += 1;
        break;
    }

}

?>
```

Deste jeito funciona, mas imaginem o tamanho que ficaria se estivessemos falando de 100, 500, 1000 variáveis linhasX.

Há alguma forma de mudar o nome da váriavel dinamicamente,  usando apenas um FOR sem SWITCH, como sugiro abaixo?

```
<?php


// crio um laço com 50 loops, por exemplo
for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++) {

    // Misturo aleatoriamente o array $umNumero
    shuffle($cincoNumeros);
    // Seleciono um array unitário (um número) no array que foi misturado. 
    $umNumero = array_slice($cincoNumeros, 0, 1);
    // Pego o valor do index do array $umNumero
    $valor = $umNumero[0];
    $linha.$valor += 1; // Incremento de uma variavel linhaX qualquer, de acordo com valor sorteado. Digamos que o valor sorteado seja 3 então, a variável a ser incrementada seria $linha3. 
}

?>
```

Sei que o nome da variavel $linha.$valor está errado. Estaria apenas concatenando, mas dá erro porque não existe essa variável "linha".

Pergunto: Há como fazer que o nome da variável possa variar de acordo com o valor sorteado?

O código ficaria mais enxuto que com o uso de switch.

Comment: talvez trocar a variável linha por um array e cada posição do array seria uma linha

Comment: Pode ser @igorhenrique vou testar. Mas de qualquer forma não terminaria tendo que usar um switch enorme? Códigos enxutos (clean) melhoram o desempenho da aplicação web, a página carrega mais rápido, facilita compreensão e manutenção do código né? Sempre que que possível procuro otimizar.

Comment: Não. Como cada posição do array representa um linha, não é necessário fazer a checagem pelo switch para somar, você acaba fazendo a soma de forma mas genérica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$linha = array();    

//crio um laço com 50 loops, por exemplo    
for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++) {    

   shuffle($cincoNumeros); 
   $umNumero = array_slice($cincoNumeros, 0, 1);       
   $valor = $umNumero[0];
   //cada linha corresponde a uma posição do array
   $linha[$valor] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Sua sugestão é uma boa solução. Até porque, pesquisei e não encontrei nada que se aproxime do que imaginei. Talvez não seja possível.